# Finding the angle of rotation for a transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, self-learning

[image]

I am trying to learn linear algebra through a self study course. I came across this slide (the picture is a screenshot of the slide). I don't understand how using the tangent formula given, $\phi$ became $\frac{-5\pi}{6}$. Can anyone explain?

Comment: I think they meant to say $\tan \varphi = -7/(-7\sqrt{3})$ which is the usual rise/run formula for the tangent.

Comment: @CyclotomicField - meaning I need to do the inverse tangent function? Doing that gave me $\frac{\pi}{6}$. Are they mistaken in their answer?

Comment: @CyclotomicField Also, would it be possible to write this generically as $\tan(\phi)=\frac{b}{a}$?

Comment: If $\tan\phi=1/\sqrt3$ then $\phi=\pi/6$ or $\phi=-5\pi/6$; in this example it is the latter because the $x$ and $y$ values are both negative. To your second question, yes.